# Move SBS 2008 VM from one Hyper-V host to another?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, windows-sbs-2008, windows-sbs

I have a box running Server 2008 R2 hosting a SBS 2008 VM on Hyper-V. This server is failing, and we would like to move the SBS 2008 VM to a new Hyper-V host.

I know cloning/moving DCs is generally unsupported, but has anyone done this? I can't really think of any reasons it wouldn't work - shutting it down and moving the physical VHD, then recreating the VM. There shouldn't be any time issues.

Any input? Anyone done this before with any success (or not?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know cloning/moving DCs is generally unsupported,

Really? I Do not. CLONING - yes (as the SSID is identical and a DC is critical on that - they need separate identities). MOVING? Where you get that from? I never heard that and it would make any maintenance on the host simply impossible.

Use export - do not JUST copy the VHD. Btw., if you upgraded to Hyper-V 2012 in time you could move that online without even shutting down ;)

Comment: MS says: "Do not use the Export feature on a virtual machine that is running a domain controller." http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2cae85b-41ac-497f-8cd1-5fbaa6740ffe(v=ws.10)#deployment_considerations_for_virtualized_domain_controllers

Comment: @justin0 you should read in context - this statement is a "***deployment*** *practice to avoid*" - there is nothing wrong with exporting it if you do not intend to run the copy in parallel with the original. BTW: an "export" will preserve the virtual hardware configuration, including interface MAC addresses - which will save you some time when bringing the machine back up again.

Comment: Exactly. Unless you can run live migration with shared nothing (2012) export/import is the only way to do it. Do it to CLONE a vm though and you are in deep deep trouble as you possibly just destroyed your forest replication. But to move them around - nothing wrong.

Comment: Agreed. Export the VM. Do not clone it and do not copy and paste it. Export/Import it.